# python "/" in function parameter list

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am new to python.
I am using python 3.5.
when I type `help( int.__index__ )` in python, I get:

```
Help on wrapper_descriptor:

__index__(self, /)
    Return self converted to an integer, if self is suitable for use as an index into a list.
```

Here is my basic question:
  what is `/`   in  `__index__(self, /)`?